# KrbException: Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes available

Tags: kerberos

I'm getting this execption every time I run the command :

```
kinit -k -t C:\Users\XXXX\user.keytab MYUSER
```

Here is the execption

```
C:\Users\XXXX>kinit -k -t C:\Users\XXXX\user.keytab MYUSER
    Exception: krb_error 0 Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes available; only have keys of following type:  No error
    KrbException: Do not have keys of types listed in default_tkt_enctypes available; only have keys of following type:
            at sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.EType.getDefaults(EType.java:280)
            at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.build(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:261)
            at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:315)
            at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(KrbAsReqBuilder.java:361)
            at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.<init>(Kinit.java:219)
            at sun.security.krb5.internal.tools.Kinit.main(Kinit.java:113)
```

My krb5.ini seems to be okay!

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = XXXX.COM
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    dns_lookup_kdc = false
    #default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    #default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96,aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
    default_tgs_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
    default_tkt_enctypes = aes des3-cbc-sha1 rc4 des-cbc-md5
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = true
    ticket_lifetime = 24h

[realms]
XXXX.COM = {
    admin_server = XXXX.com
    kdc = XXXX.com
  }

[domain_realm]
    xxxx.com= XXXX.COM
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: "aes" is not a valid enctype. The uncommented default_tgs_enctypes and default_tkt_enctypes are not valid. The commented out ones are. This is most likely the issue.

Comment: same issue, even if I use the first ones ...

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that you used an incompatible algorithm when creating the keytab. When creating the keytab. I usually use RC4-HMAC:

```
kutil
addent -password -p username@MYDOMAIN.COM -k 1 -e RC4-HMAC
wkt username.keytab
quit
```

Now it works fine.